# Object defined using classes is not inheriting color property Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I'm attempting to learn how to use Kivy and followed their pong tutorial. Now, I'm trying to make it my own by altering the code in some ways. At the moment, I am trying to make the pong paddles change color.

I have gotten one of them to do so, but the other, which I call using the same class, does not.

```
class PongPaddle(Widget):
    score = NumericProperty(0)

    def bounce_ball(self, ball):
            if self.collide_widget(ball):
                    vx, vy = ball.velocity
                    offset = (ball.center_y - self.center_y) / (self.height /2)
                    bounced = Vector(-1 * vx , vy)
                    vel = bounced * 1.1
                    ball.velocity = vel.x, vel.y + offset

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
            color = (random(), random(), random())
            with self.canvas:
                    Color(*color)

class PongBall(Widget):

    #velocity of the ball on the X and Y Axis
    velocity_x = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)  #Shorthand for referencelist
    velocity = ReferenceListProperty(velocity_x, velocity_y)

    #Used for ball movement.
    def move(self):
            self.pos = Vector(*self.velocity) + self.pos

class PongGame(Widget):
    ball = ObjectProperty(None)
    player1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    player2 = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super(PongGame, self).__init__(**kwargs)

self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self._keyboard_closed, self)
            self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)

    def _keyboard_closed(self):
            self.keyboard.unbind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)
            self._keyboard = None

    def _on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
            if keycode[1] == 'w':
                    self.player1.center_y += 10
            elif keycode[1] == 's':
                    self.player1.center_y -= 10
            elif keycode[1] == 'k':
                    self.player2.center_y += 10
            elif keycode[1] == 'l':
                    self.player2.center_y -= 10
            return True

    def serve_ball(self, vel=(4, 0)):
            self.ball.center = self.center
            self.ball.velocity = vel

    def update(self, dt):
            self.ball.move()

            self.player1.bounce_ball(self.ball)
            self.player2.bounce_ball(self.ball)

            #Bounce ball
            if (self.ball.y < 0) or (self.ball.top > self.height):
                    self.ball.velocity_y *= -1

            #Scoring
            if self.ball.x < self.x:
                    self.player2.score += 1
                    self.serve_ball(vel=(4, 0))
            if self.ball.x > self.width:
                    self.player1.score += 1
                    self.serve_ball(vel=(-4, 0))

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
            if touch.x < self.width / 3:
                    self.player1.center_y = touch.y
            if touch.x > self.width - self.width / 3:
                    self.player2.center_y = touch.y
class PongApp(App):
    def build(self):
            game = PongGame()
            game.serve_ball()
            Clock.schedule_interval(game.update, 1.0/60.0)
            return game

if __name__ == '__main__':
    PongApp().run()
```

And the accompanying KV language file.

```
#:kivy 1.8.0

<PongBall>:
    size: 50, 50
    canvas:
            Ellipse:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
<PongPaddle>:
    size: 25, 200
    canvas:
            Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

<PongGame>:
    ball: pong_ball
    player1: player_left
    player2: player_right
    canvas:
            Rectangle:
                    pos: self.center_x - 5, 0
                    size: 10, self.height
    Label:
            font_size: 70
            center_x: root.width / 4
            top: root.top - 50
            text: str(root.player1.score)
    Label:
            font_size: 70
            center_x: root.width * 3 / 4       
            text: str(root.player2.score)
    PongBall:
            id: pong_ball
            center: self.parent.center
    PongPaddle:
            id: player_left
            x: root.x
            center_y: root.center_y
    PongPaddle:
            id: player_right
            x: root.width-self.width
            center_y: root.center_y
```

Any idea why the paddle on the left is not changing color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If no Color is declared before drawing on the canvas, color instructions defaults to (1,1,1,1) which is white. 
So when you use:

```
with self.canvas:
    Color(*color)
```

You are only changing the color of objects drawn after declaring the new color. So by looking at your kv file:

```
Label:
    font_size: 70
    center_x: root.width / 4
    top: root.top - 50
    text: str(root.player1.score)
Label:
    font_size: 70
    center_x: root.width * 3 / 4       
    text: str(root.player2.score)
PongBall:
    id: pong_ball
    center: self.parent.center
PongPaddle:
    id: player_left
    x: root.x
    center_y: root.center_y
PongPaddle:
    id: player_right
    x: root.width-self.width
    center_y: root.center_y
```

The color instructions you added to the canvas after drawing player_left will get used by the widgets drawn after declaring the color(player_right). Change Pong Paddle's on_touch_down function to the following to see how Color is used with canvas  :

```
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        color = (random(), random(), random())
        with self.canvas:
            Color(*color)
            Rectangle(size=(self.width-5,self.height-5),pos=self.pos)
```

You will notice that the first Rectangle(on top of the left paddle) and the right paddle are the same color. Your second color is then used to draw the second rectangle on top of right paddle. If you want to add instructions before executing the main ones, you can use:

```
with self.canvas.before:
    Color(*color)
```

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate the help. I'll have fun tinkering thanks to your help. :-)